# mysql with php to add a row in table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, triggers, procedure

I am super confused why this does not work, since it works on my other table.

Here is procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dodaj_ubezpieczenie
         (do_nazwa_ubezpieczenia     VARCHAR(30),
 do_wysokosc_ubezpieczenia   decimal(4,2)
 )
MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
INSERT INTO ubezpieczenia
(nazwa_ubezpieczenia,wysokosc_ubezpieczenia)
VALUES
(do_nazwa_ubezpieczenia,do_wysokosc_ubezpieczenia);
END$$
```

Procedure works with example:

```
call dodaj_ubezpieczenie('lol',5);
```

here is script:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_NOTICE);
$nazwabazydanych = "projekt";

$nazwa_ubezpieczenia = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nazwa_ubezpieczenia']);
$wysokosc_ubezpieczenia = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['wysokosc_ubezpieczenia']);  


if (!$nazwa_ubezpieczenia || !$wysokosc_ubezpieczenia)

 {
        print "Nie zostały wypełnione wszystkie pola";
        exit;
 }


$db = mysql_pconnect("localhost", "root", "");
if (!$db)  
        {  
        print "Nie można nawiązać połączenia z bazą danych";
        exit;
        }

mysql_select_db("$nazwabazydanych");

$query = mysql_query("CALL dodaj_ubezpieczenie ('$nazwa_ubezpieczenia','$wysokosc_ubezpieczenia')"); 

?>
```

The use of it:

```
<form action="ubezp.php" method="post">
Nazwa ubezpieczenia: <input type="text" name="nazwa_ubezpieczenia" maxlength=30 size=31><br><br> 
Wysokość ubezpieczenia: <input type="text" name="wartosc_ubezpieczenia" maxlength=6 size=8><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Dodaj ubezpieczenie">
</form>
```

And finally the error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: wysokosc_ubezpieczenia in C:\xampp\htdocs\proj\ubezp.php on line 6
Nie zostały wypełnione wszystkie pola
```

I am really, really confused what is wrong here.

Comment: `$_POST['wysokosc_ubezpieczenia']` should be `$_POST['wartosc_ubezpieczenia']`

Comment: Or just change the second input `name="wartosc_ubezpieczenia"` to `name="wysokosc_ubezpieczenia"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be just a spelling mistake?

`$wysokosc_ubezpieczenia = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['wysokosc_ubezpieczenia']);`

Should be

`$wysokosc_ubezpieczenia = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['wartosc_ubezpieczenia']);`